# Can something "impose a threat"?

Tags: word-usage, verbs, phrase-usage

I have come across "**imposing** a threat" several times in writing. Having myself always used "**pose** a threat", I find this usage strange. Ngrams indicate that "pose/posed a threat" is much more common, but "imposed a threat" also exists as a usage. Is it a mistake, because dictionary definitions under *impose* don't appear to support this usage? If not how does it differ from "pose" semantically?

> The long-serving Glen was tautly alert to **the threat imposed** by Africans, considering them “more dangerous enemies” than either “Indians [or] Spaniards,” since they were “ready to revolt on the first opportunity and are eight times as many in number as there are white men able to bear arms," a "danger" grown greater since Oglethorpe's "unhappy expedition to St. Augustine." ([source](https://books.google.com/books?id=nzUqAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA114&dq=%22the%20threat%20imposed%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiEscLW7cjoAhWPs54KHUBCDlAQ6AEwAnoECAYQAg), by [Gerald Horne](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerald_Horne))
>
> Targeting education towards the community elders may limit **the threat imposed** by biomedical knowledge supplied by the youth on established hierarchical structures of authority. ([source](https://books.google.com/books?id=uJWuAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA117&dq=%22the%20threat%20imposed%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiEscLW7cjoAhWPs54KHUBCDlAQ6AEwAXoECAkQAg))
>
> We believed that under conditions of high work pressures and unresponsive management, the rewards for group action as a way of warding off **the threat imposed** by these conditions, regaining control over the environment, and satisfying ... ([source](https://books.google.com/books?id=VL4fBgAAQBAJ&pg=PA45&dq=%22the%20threat%20imposed%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiEscLW7cjoAhWPs54KHUBCDlAQ6AEwAHoECAUQAg#v=onepage&q=%22the%20threat%20imposed%22&f=false))
>
> This kind of art violates accepted links between objects and events, thus **imposing a threat** to meaning. ([source](https://books.google.com/books?id=IT8lDAAAQBAJ&pg=PA132&dq=%22imposing%20a%20threat%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjwv9fc8MjoAhXMup4KHS93D30Q6AEwAHoECAMQAg))

There is a lot more examples found on Google Books, seemingly too many to be considered typos/errors.

Comment: A threat is typically *posed*.  But it can also be *supposed*, *imposed*, *exposed*, *disposed (of)* and so on.

Comment: @GlobalCharm Every one of them makes sense except for _impose_. Went down the Lexico, MacMillan, MW lists for _impose_; couldn't find a corresponding line or similar example. What does _impose_ a threat in **these examples** even mean? Cuz I don't see any of them intended to carry a different meaning than "pose".

Comment: Just because it isn’t in a dictionary doesn’t mean that it isn’t real. You could, for example, imagine the title of an article or book: *The threat of tariffs, imposed and exposed.* Sometimes, there are resonances between words that a writer can exploit. Still, I have to agree that *imposing a threat* is not a typical usage.